# BackgroundColor картинки меняется на iPad версии, а на iPhone все нормально

Tags: swift

`myImage` расположена по центру, ширина и высотка картинки фиксированы.  `myImage.backgroundColor = .clear`. На iPhone версии все хорошо, картинка есть, а задний фон соответствует цвету `self.view.backgroundColor`, а на iPad версии картинка есть но задний фон залит белым цветом. Что не так ?

на iPhone

[image: на iPhone]

на iPad
[image: на iPad]

Comment: в Images.xcassetsкартинка указана как универсальная или только для iPhone?

Comment: Universal стоит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это был очередной баг Xcode или simulator'a, на реальном iPad все прошло хорошо.